# How to highlight value with line in barchart of crystal report

Tags: charts, crystal-reports

I am using line chart in crystal report. I have a requirement like below

[image]

I need to write a target line like below . I have averageVaue column,HighValue,LowValue. I need to show HighValue and Low Value with Marker and Average value as a line to show as a threshold value.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight one of the Y-axis values > Select 'Data (Y) Axis options' > Gridlines tab > Check 'Draw Custom Line at:' and enter a threshold number